# How to check logged in facebook user in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to check if a user is already logged in with facebook in ASP.NET MVC4. I'm using Facebook C# SDK.
I have this code for getting the access_token from facebook:

```
  public ActionResult FacebookCallback(string code)
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic result = fb.Post("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            client_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            redirect_uri = RedirectUri.AbsoluteUri,
            code = code
        });

        var accessToken = result.access_token;

        Session["AccessToken"] = accessToken;

        fb.AccessToken = accessToken;

        dynamic me = fb.Get("me?fields=first_name,last_name,id,email");
        string email = me.email;

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, false);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

I don't know how to check if user is already logged in. Please help.

Comment: Wouldn't you just check if `Session["AccessToken"]` already exists and if so attempt to use that to authenticate? If it fails you force the user re-authenticate.

Comment: @James I think this will only check if Session variable exist or not. How can I check if somebody already logged into Facebook in other tab and trying to access my application for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way in my opinion if your willing to checkout Facebooks javascript SDK, then there is a `FB.getLoginStatus` method which will give you the info you need.

Taken from facebook's dev site:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
});
```

There is also the `user_online_presence` extended permission [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/). Probably not what you want, but using FQL, you can request the `online_presence` field [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user), but note this only returns if the user is logged into facebook user chat.

Comment: thanks for your reply but Is there any way of doing this using Facebook C# SDK?

Comment: From what im aware there isnt a way to do what your asking server side. Just the Javascript route via FB.getLoginStatus